My chrome extension isn't returning the current URL (chrome://newtab/) in the console
My chrome extension is coded to log the current url in the console, but it's not. the URL I'm trying to identify is the chrome://newtab/ page, and previously loaed ones are showing up, but whenever I try and open a new tab, it doesn't show the URL until Isitch tabs and then switch back again. I'm pretty new to coding, and using more than a bit of help from ChatGPT on this, (a school project) so I have absolutely no idea what's causing this issue.
My background.js
// Array to hold URLs of sites that should always stay open
let whitelist = ["spotify.com", "chrome://extensions/", "chrome://newtab/", "chrome://extensions/", "chrome://bookmarks/", "chrome://settings/", "chrome://history/", "chrome://downloads/"];

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(data => {
    if (data.event === 'onStart') {
        console.log("Handling onStart event in background script");
        handleOnStartEvent(data.saveData);
    }
});

function handleOnStartEvent(saveData) {
    console.log("saveData", saveData);
    chrome.storage.local.set(saveData);

    const timeInMinutes = parseInt(saveData.timeId) || 0;
    const customTimeInMinutes = parseInt(saveData.customTimeId) || 0;

    if (timeInMinutes > 0) {
        console.log(`Setting timeout for ${timeInMinutes} minutes`);
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`Time's up after ${timeInMinutes} minutes!`);
            // Any additional actions to perform after the specified duration
        }, timeInMinutes * 60 * 1000);
    }

    if (customTimeInMinutes > 0) {
        console.log(`Setting custom timeout for ${customTimeInMinutes} minutes`);
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`Custom time's up after ${customTimeInMinutes} minutes!`);
            // Any additional actions to perform after the specified duration
        }, customTimeInMinutes * 60 * 1000);
    }

    // Retrieve the list of valid websites from storage
    chrome.storage.local.get("websiteId", function(result) {
        const validWebsites = result.websiteId || "";
        console.log("Valid websites:", validWebsites);
    });
}

// Listen for tab activation events
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(activeInfo => {
    chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, tab => {
        const tabUrl = tab.url;
        console.log("Current tab URL:", tabUrl); // Log the current tab URL

        // Check if the tab URL is in the whitelist
        const isInWhitelist = whitelist.some(url => tabUrl.includes(url));

        console.log("Is the tab in the whitelist?", isInWhitelist); // Log whether the tab is in the whitelist

        // Check if the tab is the new tab page
        const isNewTabPage = tabUrl.startsWith("chrome://newtab/");
        console.log("Is the tab the new tab page?", isNewTabPage); // Log whether the tab is the new tab page

        // Wait for the new tab page to fully load before executing the logic
        if (isNewTabPage) {
            chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function onCompleted(details) {
                if (details.tabId === tab.id) {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        // Execute the logic to determine if the tab should be closed
                        executeTabClosingLogic(tabUrl, tab.id, isInWhitelist);
                    }, 500); // Delay of 500 milliseconds (0.5 second)
                    chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.removeListener(onCompleted); // Remove the listener after execution
                }
            });
        } else {
            setTimeout(() => {
                // Execute the logic to determine if the tab should be closed
                executeTabClosingLogic(tabUrl, tab.id, isInWhitelist);
            }, 500); // Delay of 500 milliseconds (0.5 second)
        }
    });
});

// Function to execute the logic to determine if the tab should be closed
function executeTabClosingLogic(tabUrl, tabId, isInWhitelist) {
    // Retrieve the list of valid websites from storage
    chrome.storage.local.get("validWebsites", function(result) {
        const websiteIds = result.validWebsites || ""; // Retrieve the list of valid websites
        const websiteIdsArray = websiteIds.split(' '); // Split into array
        const isCurrentTabValid = websiteIdsArray.some(website => tabUrl.includes(website.trim()));

        console.log("Is current tab valid?", isCurrentTabValid); // Log whether the current tab is valid

        if (!isCurrentTabValid && !isInWhitelist) {
            // If the tab is not valid and not in the whitelist, close it
            console.log("Closing current tab:", tabUrl);
            // Attempt to close the tab after a short delay
            setTimeout(() => {
                chrjome.tabs.remove(tabId, () => {
                    console.log("Tab closed:", tabUrl);
                });
            }, 1000); // Delay of 1000 milliseconds (1 second)
        } else {
            console.log("Current tab is valid or in the whitelist. Not closing.");
        }
    });
}


This problem causes my code to immediately close any new tab page, and sometimes bug out and close some on the whitelist.

chrome:// tabs don't run content scripts. Use chrome.tabs.onUpdated in your background.js for such tabs.
